# IF formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have a formula =IF(LEFT(N11,2)="41","Y","N") where if any thing with in that field equals 42 then return a Y if not a N, I am trying to figure out how I can nest in the IF formula to where it would say if it equals 41, 42, or 43 than Y if not then N.

Answer (score 5):

You can use OR operator to put multiple logical equation as below

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(N11,2)="41",LEFT(N11,2)="42",LEFT(N11,2)="43"),"Y","N")
```

Comment: You could also shorten that as follows: `=IF(OR(LEFT(N11,2)={"41","42","43"}),"Y","N")`